# CodeIgniter 4 migration fails but the equivalent MySQL query does not

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter newbie here.
I am trying to create a migration in CodeIgniter 4 and it keeps failing due to the same issue.
I tried to run the - to my understanding - equivalent query in MySQL and that one worked without problems.

`2024-03-21-091038_CreateCartTable.php` migration file:

```php
class CreateCartTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {

        $this->forge->addField([
            'id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true,
                'null' => false,
            ],
            'productCode' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '15',
                'null' => false,
            ],
            'quantity' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'default' => 1,
                'null' => false,
            ],
            'customerNumber' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'null' => false,
            ],
            'createdAt' => [
                'type' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            ],
            'updatedAt' => [
                'type' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
                'onUpdate' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->forge->addKey('id', true);

        $this->forge->addForeignKey('customerNumber', 'customers', 'customerNumber');
        $this->forge->addForeignKey('productCode', 'products', 'productCode');

        $this->forge->createTable('cart', true);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('cart', true);
    }
}
```

RUnning this migration results in the following:

```
$ php spark migrate:refresh

CodeIgniter v4.4.6 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2024-03-21 12:52:32 UTC+00:00

Rolling back migrations to batch:  0
        Rolling back: (App) 2024-03-14-135404_App\Database\Migrations\AddOfficeLatLon
        Rolling back: (App) 2024-03-14-111807_App\Database\Migrations\AddAboutToOffices
Done rolling back migrations.
Running all new migrations...
[CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException]
Referencing column 'productCode' and referenced column 'productCode' in foreign key constraint 'cart_productCode_foreign' are incompatible.
at SYSTEMPATH/Database/BaseConnection.php:647

  Caused by:
  [CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException]
  Referencing column 'productCode' and referenced column 'productCode' in foreign key constraint 'cart_productCode_foreign' are incompatible.
  at SYSTEMPATH/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php:311

  Caused by:
  [mysqli_sql_exception]
  Referencing column 'productCode' and referenced column 'productCode' in foreign key constraint 'cart_productCode_foreign' are incompatible.
  at SYSTEMPATH/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php:306
```

MySQL Query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE classicmodels.cart (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    productCode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    customerNumber INT NOT NULL ,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (customerNumber) REFERENCES customers(customerNumber),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (productCode) REFERENCES products(productCode)
);
```

Running this query results in the following:
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)`

I tried to run the migration several times and used several variations to insert the data, I always get the same error message:
`Referencing column 'productCode' and referenced column 'productCode' in foreign key constraint 'cart_productCode_foreign' are incompatible.`
I have read the CodeIgniter documentation for the [forge class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/forge.html) and [migrations](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/migration.html), if I did not miss anything, I am doing everything according to protocol. I also looked on previous posts here on stackoverflow, none of the issues seem to be relevant to mine, I am thinking I might just be missing a trivial point and my usage of the forge class in incomplete or incorrect.

UPDATE:

I commented out the fields `createdAt` `updatedAt` and the line with the `productCode` constraint. The first two I removed, because I was getting this error: `Invalid default value for 'createdAt'`. Now the migration works just fine. Also I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, and the codeigniter console tells me the current time is `2024-03-21 14:21:10 UTC+00:00` even though I am in an UTC+01:00 timezone, and it is currently 15:21. Maybe this is also relevant.

Comment: `productCode' => [ 'type' => 'VARCHAR',` Is this also defined as `VARCHAR` in the `products` table

Comment: Yes, I ran the mysql query and double checked. The columns are identical to one another in both tables.

Comment: Is the related table `products` created prior to table `cart` during the process?
Could you try to FK to an `int` field, just to test?

Comment: @b126 I commented out the foreign key constraint for the `productCode` row and tested it. The foreign key `customerNumber` is an `int`, that one does not throw an error. I did get another error thought, saying '`Invalid default value for 'createdAt'`'. I am not sure why so much is going wrong here...

Comment: @Findus : maybe the order of things done is not the good one? I am not an expert. I suggest you to ask the official [CI forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/), they are quite reactive.

Comment: please compare the output of `echo $this->db->getLastQuery(); die();` with your raw query

Comment: If @Vickel solution doesn't work, also look in System\Database\Forge.php and look for something like ` $sql = $this->_createTable($table, false, $attributes);`. Underneath output `print_r($sql)` and see what gets generated. That might direct you further.

Comment: Try using current timestamp like this: `new RawSql('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')`.
Ref: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/dbmgmt/forge.html#raw-sql-strings-as-default-values